# No logro ampliar la grafica para que entren los datos a mostrar

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas! Les comparto es el código que usé para armar una grafica que muestre los datos de la función corr, pero no logro hacer que el texto de los nros arrojados en la correlación entren en la grafica.
Ya están centrados pero no sé como agrandar la grafica para que quepa el texto:

```
Correlacion = base.corr(method="pearson")


plt.matshow(Correlacion , cmap= "bwr" , width= 4000 ,vmin=-1 , vmax= 1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(range(16) , Correlacion.columns , rotation= 90 )
plt.yticks(range(16) , Correlacion.columns)

for i in range(len(Correlacion.columns)):
    for j in range (len(Correlacion.columns)):
        plt.text(i , j  , round(Correlacion.iloc[i, j], 2) , ha="center"  , va="center")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.